# How I can handle more than one endpoint in one page different views Android-Kotlin ? (In fragment)

Tags: android, kotlin, endpoint, kotlin-flow

Flow ->
We have one page with sections&recycler views&custom views etc. ( In screen shoot )
Every single view&section&rv has a different endpoint ( In screen shoot )
I want to show which endpoint response return success. ( Should I use flow combine? )
I use flows(shared&state) with UI events.
You can give some github examples or simply explain.

[image]

Comment: Is it true ? successFlow.combine ( 1.endpoint flow, 2.endpoint flow, 3.endpoint flow, 4.endpoint flow, 5.endpoint flow) { when 1. endpoint success -> show 1. view &  2. endpoint success -> show 2 . view .... } observe every single case in uı ( fragment )

Comment: Please add your code & attempts to make this work. This way we can better understand your goal and see if something is wrong.

Comment: @gioravered I don't have code I want to understand before development.

Comment: Ok. So please elaborate on what you mean by "endpoint" and more about your goal

Comment: @gioravered endpoints mean requests to backend services.  The goal is to divide 1 request to single small requests.

Comment: Then you can have a View Model that (through a repository or not..) interact with an API (backend..) and prepare the data for each view.